# Cleanup on S3 / AWS

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a bucket on Amazon S3 / AWS. It contains a hierarchy of folders and subfolders. I would like to delete all sub-sub folders called "flac" and "mp3".
Example: [Bucket]> 299-399> Flac

I have installed AWS CLI on my iMac (High Sierra). Is it possible to create a batch command that performs this in one chop or possibly in two laps (one for Flac and one for mp3)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aws s3 rm` command. Here's [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html#rm).

Try:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://bucket/ --exclude="*" --include="*/Flac/*"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://bucket/ --exclude="*" --include="*/mp3/*"
```

To learn about how to use `--exclude` and `--include`, you can refer to [See Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters).

Comment: Thank you very much, LiuChang. Much appreciated :-)